# jquery .css() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know why when I use the .css() function of jQuery it returns me this:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

My code is this:

HTML:

```
<div class="photo1 sliderPhoto">d</div>
<div class="photo2 sliderPhoto">d</div>
<div class="photo3 sliderPhoto">d</div>
<div class="photo4 sliderPhoto">d</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sliderPhoto{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.photo1{
    background-image: url('../photos/ph1.jpg');
    z-index: 6;
}
.photo2{
    background-image: url('../photos/ph2.jpg');
    z-index: 6; 
    display: none;
}
.photo3{
    background-image: url('../photos/ph3.jpg');
    z-index: 6;
    display: none;
}
.photo4{
    background-image: url('../photos/ph4.jpg');
    z-index: 6;
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery on $(document).ready:

```
$photos = [$(".photo1")[0], $(".photo2")[0], $(".photo3")[0], $(".photo4")[0]];
$photos[0].css("z-index");
```

when I type this jQuery code it doesn't work :(
but this $photos[0] returns the exact div I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$photos[0].css("z-index");
```

Should be:

```
$($photos[0]).css("z-index");
```

You have to convert DOM element back into a jQuery Object to use jQuery function.

Alternatively, it may be more efficient to simply filter the element using jQuery so that no conversion is required -

```
$photos.first().css("z-index");
```

See http://api.jquery.com/first/ for more details on the .first() method

Comment: This gets the first DOM element from the jQuery object, and then converts it back to a jQuery object. Does it not make sense to use the jQuery .first() method (http://api.jquery.com/first/) so that you can still use the .css() method on the result, rather than get a DOM element and convert it back to a whole new jQuery object.

Comment: @pwdst yeah that is a better approach.

Comment: @GauravKalyan I have taken the liberty of editing your answer to add in the alternative approach, whilst retaining your original answer as is

Comment: @pwdst I was going to do the same. Thank you. I was just trying to point the OP mistake that OP is applying a jQuery function to DOM element.

Comment: @GauravKalyan Your answer was spot on in that regard - and still deserves to be the accepted answer. I just wanted to expand on it with the jQuery methods as an alternative to the filtering approach originally used by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You try to access the `css()` method on a DOM object not on a jQuery instance.

The expression `$element[0]` refers to the real DOM node.

You should either change the expression that creates your `$photos` array to this:

```
$photos = [$(".photo1"), $(".photo2"), $(".photo3"), $(".photo4")];
```

(and adapt other code references aswell) or re-wrap each DOM node using `$()`

```
$($photos[0]).css("z-index");
```

---

Note: you could also find the elements by the `.sliderPhoto` selector, getting a jQuery collection of four items in your example. You can then access individual nodes using `eq()` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) or even iterate using `each()` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$(".sliderPhoto").eq(0) // first element
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the first element of a collection of object you should use pseudo selector :eq

```
$photos = [$(".photo1:eq(0)"), $(".photo2:eq(0)"),$(".photo3:eq(0)"), $(".photo4:eq(0)")];
```

but if you have only one instance of photo1, you can consider use id instead a class, or apply your rule at all the class.

Answer (score 0):

Since your class selector would return only 1 element, you should do it like this.

```
$photos = [$(".photo1"), $(".photo2"), $(".photo3"), $(".photo4")];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/62x9mdj6/

Answer (score 0):

That is because `$(".photo1")[0]` returns a **DOM node**, which is unmanipulatable by jQuery methods because they work with jQuery objects. Instead, try:

```
$photos = [$(".photo1"), $(".photo2"), $(".photo3"), $(".photo4")];
$photos[0].css("z-index");
```

If you do not want to cache the `.photo(n)` elements on the fly, simply use an array of classes instead:

```
photos = [".photo1", ".photo2", ".photo3", ".photo4"];
$(photos[0]).css("z-index");
```

Note that I prefer to use `$` for jQuery objects but not for non-jQuery ones (i.e. second example).

Answer (score 0):

This works. Remove the index in the array. You don't need them anyway. Since you do not have more than one of each class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$photos = [$(".photo1"), $(".photo2"), $(".photo3"), $(".photo4")];
alert($photos[0].css('z-index'));

});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n8pqj2wg/